# Animate every item in a ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I would like to, on long press on a item in the list, animate in a checkbox on the leading end of the list item for every list item like in [this video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18qoobjbKX4TY6AUyvF0mg_Hb_nrlUHgp/view?usp=sharing).

I have tried with implicit animations, here under is my list item code.

```
class InspectionItemWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Inspection inspection;
  final Function(Inspection, bool) selected;

  const InspectionItemWidget(
      {Key? key, required this.inspection, required this.selected})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<InspectionItemWidget> createState() => _InspectionItemWidgetState();
}

class _InspectionItemWidgetState extends State<InspectionItemWidget> {
  File? _imageFile;
  final _duration = const Duration(milliseconds: 400);
  late double _selectWidth;
  late double _opacity;
  late bool _selected;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _selectWidth = 0.0;
    _opacity = 0.0;
    _selected = false;

    di<EventBus>().on<InspectionSelectEvent>().listen((event) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          if (event.selectMode) {
            _selectWidth = 60.0;
            _opacity = 1.0;
          } else {
            _selectWidth = 0.0;
            _opacity = 0.0;
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AppLocalizations loc = AppLocalizations.of(context)!;

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 2, 16, 8),
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 80,
        child: PhysicalModel(
          color: Colors.white,
          elevation: 8,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              _buildSelectBox(),
              _buildImage(),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(getStatusName(widget.inspection.status, loc),
                        style: TextStyle(color: colorMedium)),
                    Text(getTypeName(widget.inspection.type, loc),
                        style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    Text(formatDateTime(widget.inspection.created)),
                    Text(widget.inspection.description)
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSelectBox() {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: _duration,
      width: _selectWidth,
      child: AnimatedOpacity(
        opacity: _opacity,
        duration: _duration,
        child: Checkbox(
            value: _selected,
            onChanged: (_) {
              setState(() {
                _selected = !_selected;
              });
              widget.selected(widget.inspection, _selected);
            }),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildImage() {
    if (widget.inspection.imageName.isNotEmpty) {
      if (_imageFile != null) {
        return SizedBox(
          width: 80,
          height: 80,
          child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
              child: Image.file(_imageFile!,
                  width: 72, height: 72, fit: BoxFit.fill)),
        );
      } else {
        return FutureBuilder<void>(
            future: _loadImage(widget.inspection.imageName),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return SizedBox(
                width: 80,
                height: 80,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                  child: snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done
                      ? Image.file(_imageFile!,
                          width: 72, height: 72, fit: BoxFit.fill)
                      : Container(),
                ),
              );
            });
      }
    }
    return const SizedBox(
        width: 80,
        height: 80,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
          child: Icon(Icons.no_photography, size: 72),
        ));
  }

  Future<void> _loadImage(String name) async {
    Directory appDocumentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String appDocumentsPath = appDocumentsDirectory.path;
    String filePath = '$appDocumentsPath/images/$name';
    _imageFile = File(filePath);
  }
}
```

But the animation is not happening?

Also, I am using a event bus to start the animation for every item, is there a better way for this? A way to signal every item to start the animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in multiple ways. Here's one simple solution using [`AnimatedCrossFade`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedCrossFade-class.html).
For time being, I did it for just one item (other items won't show an unchecked checkbox, but you could do it easily with any state management solution of your choice).

### Basic Example

```dart
class AnimationDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  AnimationDemoState createState() => AnimationDemoState();
}

class AnimationDemoState extends State<AnimationDemo> {
  bool isAllSelected = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Item(
          (index + 1).toString(),
          isAllSelected: isAllSelected,
          onLongPress: () {
            setState(() {
              isAllSelected = !isAllSelected;
            });
          },
        );
      },
      itemCount: 20,
    );
  }
}

class Item extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final bool isAllSelected;
  final VoidCallback onLongPress;

  const Item(this.title,
      {required this.isAllSelected, required this.onLongPress});

  @override
  ItemState createState() => ItemState();
}

class ItemState extends State<Item> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool isSelected = false; 
  //todo: instead of this, use a global variable with any state management solution to show unchecked boxes for others

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      onLongPress: () {
        setState(() {
          isSelected = !isSelected;
        });
      },
      title: Text(widget.title),
      minLeadingWidth: 0,
      leading: AnimatedCrossFade(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
        reverseDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        secondCurve: Curves.linearToEaseOut,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        firstChild: Checkbox(value: true, onChanged: (_) {}),
        secondChild: const SizedBox(),
        crossFadeState:
            isSelected ? CrossFadeState.showFirst : CrossFadeState.showSecond,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Output

[image: Demo GIF]

Comment: Hm it was never my animation that was failing, it was my state management solution. But I like the cross fade animation, thank you